# Вывод значения с БД в таблицу

Tags: php, html, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица где должны выводиться значения каждые 20-30 секунд в каждой ячейке типа "Насос-1", "Насос-2","Насос-3","Насос-4" выводились значения с базы данных  ИЛИ БЕЗ ОБНОВЛЕНИЯ ТАК КАК ЭТО ПОТОМ БУДЕТ ДЕЛАТЬСЯ КОНТРОЛЛЕРОМ . СКРИПТ И HTML  сбросил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<form action="" method="POST">
          <div class="table1">
          <table class="table_price">
<caption>Таблица №1</caption>
<tr>
  <th>Наименование</th>
  <th colspan="2">Запись</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Насос 1</td>
  <td><input type="number" name="Pump_1" id="" value="<?php echo ($result['Pump_1']); ?>" min="0" max="100" step="1"></td>
  <td><input type="button"  class="but1" name="b1" value="Обработать" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Насос 2</td>
  <td><input type="number" name="Pump_1" id="" value="<?php echo ($result['Pump_1']); ?>" min="0" max="100" step="1"></td>
  <td><input type="button"  class="but1" name="b2" value="Обработать" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Насос 3</td>
  <td><input type="number" name="Pump_1" id="" value="<?php echo ($result['Pump_1']); ?>" min="0" max="100" step="1"></td>
  <td><input type="button"  class="but1" name="b3" value="Обработать" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Насос 4</td>
  <td><input type="number" name="Pump_1" id="" value="<?php echo ($result['Pump_1']); ?>" min="0" max="100" step="1"></td>
  <td><input type="button"  class="but1" name="b4" value="Обработать" ></td>
</tr>

<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($link ,"SELECT `ID`, `Pump_1`, FROM `mybd`");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $str=mb_convert_encoding('mybd', "UTF-8", "cp-1251");
    echo     '<td>'.$result['Pump_1'].'</td>';
}
?>                  
</table>
          </div>
          </form>
```

подключение для BD

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";    
    $user="root";        
    $pass="a-1800";             
    $db_name="mybd";   
    $link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db_name); 
    $cod=mysqli_set_charset( $link,'utf8' );

    $sql = mysqli_query( $link,'UPDATE `TABLES_1`TABLES_2`TABLES_3`TABLES_4` SET '
    .'`Pump_1` = "'.$_POST['Pump_1'].'",'
    .'`Pump_2` = "'.$_POST['Pump_2'].'",'
    .'`Pump_3` = '.$_POST['Pump_3'].' ','
    .'`Pump_4` = "'.$_POST['Pump_4'].' '
    .'WHERE `ID` = '.$_GET['red_id']);
    ?>
```

Comment: так в чем проблема? где текст ошибки/запроса? что именно не получается?

Comment: Не выводит с базы данных числа в ячейки

Comment: покажите Ваш код

Comment: Все ,вписал код ,а то вчера почему-то не хотело выводить , глюконуло )

Comment: Это я вписал для ТАБЛИЦЫ - 1

Comment: Вот тут судя по всему $sql = mysqli_query($link ,"SELECT `ID`, `Pump_1`, FROM `mybd`"); лишняя запятая поле Pump_1

Comment: Так же посмотрите на код Update. Для Pump_1 и 2 он отличается от Pump_3 и 4.

Comment: Очевидно, ошибки синтаксиса SQL. Выведите текстом строку запроса (которую Вы передаете вторым параметром в `mysqli_query()`) и  проверьте ее вручную.

Comment: И похоже что тут несоответствие наименований (на форме) атрибутам `name` у инпутов. Вообще, все как-то усложнено и запутанно...